# Why everytime I see all the data in recyclerview and writing anything, index 0 always restarting and my write gone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I use recyclerview and custom layout manager. The problem is like in video (i give a link from youtube).

I writing anything each item and after last item , index number 0 (first item) like restarting (reset to default). My writing is gone , but all item except first item are still have my writing.

How to solve it?
I have give this code for recycler view

```
    rvImage.setItemViewCacheSize(sliderItems.size());
```

this is link video for bug
[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXNWJlEepN0)

thanks before

Comment: You have to store whatever you wrote in model, and display that model value `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Yeah, i have store the item in model "SliderItem". You can see my code in this link https://github.com/lordrians/ImageSlider

Comment: Take another variable in `SliderItem.java`  like, bitmap or something that suite with your requirement and store values in that variable.

Comment: But, i just wanna store url the image from my API. And the problem is, my canvas to paint anything in first item always gone except all items. I'm very confuse and stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Recyclerview` recycle its view every time they appear on your screen. That's why you are not able to see whatever you changed in your `ViewHolder`.

You need to save your changes in your **model** or **getter/setter** before moving to next position.

Here I am giving you an example of `recyclerview` with **name** and **nickname**.

User can manually enter **nickname** using `EditTextView`

here is Model class

```
public class SampleModel {
    private String name, nick_name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNick_name() {
        return nick_name;
    }

    public void setNick_name(String nick_name) {
        this.nick_name = nick_name;
    }
}
```

Here is my OnBindViewHolder logic to save edittext value.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SampleModel sampleModel = list.get(position);
        holder.tvName.setText(sampleModel.getName());
        holder.etNickName.setText(sampleModel.getNick_name());

        holder.etNickName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                sampleModel.setNick_name(editable.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Now you can see I'm saving edit text value in model.

Now you can use this reference and try to make it working with your model.

Comment: Sorry to late, Thanks btw for solution. But i have do this before, in model have Getter & Setter. In adapter i use "getImageUrl" for getting url image from server. And still gone when drawing something in first item